# (JavaFX) Using stage.setResizable(false) Is Giving Me Two "X"s For Closing The Scene

Tags: javafx

As the title says, the following code is not working as intended. The setResizable(false) should just remove the "maximise" option from the window, however instead it is giving me two X's as shown in the picture.

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("IXOM Analysis Tool");
    stage.setResizable(false);
```

[image]

It's not like both X's even work (just the inner one)

Any help removing this second "X" is appreciated

Comment: You need to tell us what additional APIs you are using; this screenshot obviously shows a non-default JavaFX `Stage`.

Comment: #setResizable is not going to remove the middle button, it's going to disable it. The button will still be there but you won't be able to click it. There's not much other information so it's harder to help you since this looks like a custom stage, the problem could be a couple of things.

Comment: Hi, the only additional thing is this class extends "Application"